# What should I write here in this function to calculate the values from the input?

Tags: python

I am currently trying to create a program to calculate the total of customer's purchases for a bookstore, however I am currently stuck on the part where I have to create a function for calculating all the input values. So far, I can only do the menu part (the function that returns the input values) and even then I'm not entirely sure I'm doing it right. I also need to save the customers' purchase record to a text file, but that's a story for another day. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I tried using global to pass down the values from the RainbowStationary() function to the Total() function but it didn't work.

```
def RainbowStationary():

    print("~~ Rainbow Stationary ~~")
    a = int(input("A4 Paper (Canon): "))
    b = int(input("A4 Paper (rainbow): "))
    c = int(input("Long Ruler: "))
    d = int(input("Short Ruler: "))
    e = int(input("Blue Pen: "))
    f = int(input("Red Pen: "))
    g = int(input("Black Pen: "))
    h = int(input("2B Pencil: "))
    return a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h

def Total():
    I'm not sure what I'm supposed to write here. But this is the part where it is supposed to calculate the price for all those items in def RainbowStationary().
Oh, and this is the price list that I want to use:

    A4 paper (canon): 8.9
    A4 paper (rainbow): 7.5
    Long ruler: 0.85
    Short ruler: 0.55
    Blue Pen: 0.65
    Red Pen: 0.65
    Black Pen: 0.65
    2B Pencil: 2.4
```

I have no error messages, but here are the Expected results:

```
"~~ Rainbow Stationary ~~
A4 Paper (Canon): 1
A4 Paper (rainbow): 1
Long Ruler: 1
Short Ruler: 1
Blue Pen: 1
Red Pen:1
Black Pen: 1
2B Pencil: 1

Total: 22.15
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* pass the quantities for the different goods as parameters to the function and return the sum of their respective prices:

```
def RainbowStationary():
    print("~~ Rainbow Stationary ~~")
    a = int(input("A4 Paper (Canon): "))
    b = int(input("A4 Paper (rainbow): "))
    c = int(input("Long Ruler: "))
    d = int(input("Short Ruler: "))
    e = int(input("Blue Pen: "))
    f = int(input("Red Pen: "))
    g = int(input("Black Pen: "))
    h = int(input("2B Pencil: "))
    return a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h

def Total(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h):
    return a * 8.9 + b * 7.5 + c * 0.85 + d * 0.55 + e * 0.65 + f * 0.65 + g * 0.65 + h * 2.4

goods = RainbowStationary()
price = Total(*goods)
print("Total: %.2f" % price)
```

However, this is very repetitive, and very hard to extend, or even just to change the prices. Instead, you could use a dictionary, mapping wares to prices, and just loop the items in that dictionary:

```
prices = {"A4 paper (canon)": 8.9,
          "A4 paper (rainbow)": 7.5,
          "Long ruler": 0.85,
          "Short ruler": 0.55,
          "Blue Pen": 0.65,
          "Red Pen": 0.65,
          "Black Pen": 0.65,
          "2B Pencil": 2.4}

print("~~ Rainbow Stationary ~~")
total = 0
for good in prices:
    n = int(input("%s: " % good))
    total += prices[good] * n
print("Total: %.2f" % total)
```

Of course, you can still split it into two function by storing the quantities in another dictionary and returning that instead of a dozen individual variables:

```
def RainbowStationary():
    print("~~ Rainbow Stationary ~~")
    quantities = {}
    for good in prices:
        n = int(input("%s: " % good))
        quantities[good] = n
    return quantities

def Total(quantities):
    return sum(n * prices[g] for g, n in quantities.items())

goods = RainbowStationary()
price = Total(goods)
print("Total: %.2f" % price)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out. However, what I'm really trying to do is to separate the functions into modules. The first one might be what I'm looking for,

Comment: @tobias_k Hint: Your `n` in the first code example is never used.

Comment: @glglgl Whops, that happens when you just hammer the 1 key for testing...

Answer (score 1):

use dictionary and iterate over its items, you can just do it like:

```
prices = {"A4 paper (canon)": 8.9,
    "A4 paper (rainbow)": 7.5,
    "Long ruler": 0.85,
    "Short ruler": 0.55,
    "Blue Pen": 0.65,
    "Red Pen": 0.65,
    "Black Pen": 0.65,
    "2B Pencil": 2.4
}


def RainbowStationary():
    total = 0
    for key,val in prices.items():
        stack = int(input(key + ": "))
        total = total + (stack*val)
    print("Total: %.2f" % total)

RainbowStationary()
```

output:

```
A4 paper (canon): 3
A4 paper (rainbow): 4
Long ruler: 5
Short ruler: 3
Blue Pen: 2
Red Pen: 1
Black Pen: 2
2B Pencil: 3
Total: 73.05
```